# How do I correctly use wildcards in a prepared statement?

Tags: c#, sql-server, prepared-statement

My SQL prepared statement using a wildcard is returning zero records. All of the examples I've found do not use the .Prepare() method, which requires the SqlParameter to have a specified type. So when I switch my parameter setup to using `.AddWithValue("@cid", cid+"%")` Prepare() throws an exception about not having an explicitly set type.

```
ctx.Open();
string sql = "SELECT GRAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE FROM GRADUATES WHERE GRADUATES_ID LIKE @cid";
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand(sql,ctx);
SqlParameter id = new SqlParameter("@cid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 7);
id.Value = string.Format("{0}%", cid);
query.Parameters.Add(id);
//query.Prepare();
SqlDataReader rs = query.ExecuteReader();

string grad_date = "";
while (rs.Read())
{
  //no records =(
  grad_date = rs["GRAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE"].ToString();
  Console.WriteLine("grad date: "+grad_date);
}
rs.Close();
ctx.Close();
```

Comment: id.Value = string.Format("{0}%", cid);

Comment: Hello SQL Injection

Comment: @BrendanGreen In a prepared statement?

Comment: @TonyDong That doesn't solve the issue, I still get zero records. I think that doesn't work because the sql has to have single quotes around the value. The sql needs to end up looking like: `SELECT GRAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE FROM GRADUATES WHERE GRADUATES_ID LIKE '0123456%'`

Comment: Tony Dong is right, the value must be an unquoted string.  Try with `=` instead of `LIKE` and see what you get.  Solve the problem one step at a time, not multiple steps at once.

Comment: Can you show us the exact exception, please?

Comment: @Rob I'm testing the code with a cid that I know exists. I have access to the database and the above query returns the record I'm expecting. My code above doesn't actually throw any exception, it just fails to return any records when I know there should be one. I'm using a Console.WriteLine in the while (rs.Read()) loop and it never outputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you changed

```
id.Value = string.Format("{0}%", cid);
```

and removed

```
query.Prepare();
```

It will return all results for you.
I tested on my local and I don't know why you need prepared here?

Comment: We can blame that on my just not fully understanding the purpose of `.Prepare()`. However, I made those changes and I'm still not seeing any records returned. I'll update my code in the OP.

Comment: @dusk Can we double check that your database *actually* has those values? Can you run the query `DECLARE @cid VARCHAR(7)`
`SET @cid = 'something%'`
`SELECT GRAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE FROM GRADUATES WHERE GRADUATES_ID LIKE @cid` directly, and check the results?

Comment: Well hell. I think that stumbles onto the issue here. The cid is a 7 digit varchar, but the wildcard makes it 8. So even though the basic query works, when I do the declare & set statements it failed. When I changed the 7 to 8 it worked. Thank you @Rob and Tony for all of your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Bit basic, but it works:

Using pre-set variables, populate them, then pass them into the SQL Query function.

```
string id = //value

void SQL Query(id)
{
    string idFilter = null;
    if (id != null)
        idFilter = "WHERE GRADUATES_ID LIKE @cid"
    else
        idFilter = String.Empty;

    conn.Open();

    string sql = "SELECT GRAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE FROM GRADUATES " + idFilter;
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, ctx);

    if (id != null)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", id)
}
```

(Apologies for the horrendous structure/terrible syntax)

Comment: The issue with using `.AddWithValue()` seems to be that `.Prepare()` requires that the parameter have an explicitly set type.

Comment: Not much experience with SQL, but do you *need* to use the `.Prepare()`?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. I've been using it everywhere else to build prepared statements and have only run into issues here with a wildcard. Examples I've looked at with wildcards don't seem to use `.Prepare()` but they also don't use `.ExecuteReader()`. When I initially started learning how to use the System.Data libraries, everything I looked at was using the `.Prepare()`.

Comment: @dusk I believe using it is a good practise, as it works as a kind of "failsafe" (if there's something wrong with your statement, it will throw an exception). But if you know your statement is sound, then you shouldn't need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this?

```
string sql = "SELECT GRAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE FROM GRADUATES WHERE GRADUATES_ID LIKE @cid + '%'";
```

or if `@cid` isn't always a varchar

```
string sql = @"SELECT GRAD_COMMENCEMENT_DATE 
FROM GRADUATES WHERE GRADUATES_ID LIKE CONVERT(VARCHAR,@cid) + '%'";
```